# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto' in kivymd app

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd, pyrebase

I am compiling an android app using buildozer however even I compile it shows no module named crypto in the logs and then stops even though I gave pycryptodome as a requirement in the buildozer spec file, it seems the module crypto didn't install.

Here are my requirements from the  buildozer spec file:

```
requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd,kivy-garden.mapview,kivymd-extensions.akivymd,pyrebase,wrapt,deprecated,plyer,jwcrypto,pyasn1_modules,jnius,geopy,Pillow,requests,chardet,idna,urllib3,brotlipy,cryptography,Certifi,PySocks,win-inet-pton,requests-toolbelt,pyparsing,pyasn1,gcloud,httplib2,googleapis-common-protos,oauth2client,protobuf,six,httplib2,rsa,six,python-jwt,
,pycryptodome,deprecated,wrapt,sphinx,configparser,tox,importlib-metadata,bump2version,importlib-resources,sphinxcontrib-websupport,zipp,pyTest,pyTest-Cox,importlib-metadata,typing-extensions,ipython,packaging,pep517,pyfakefs,flufl.flake8,pytest-perf,pytest-black,pytest-mytest,importlib-resources,jaraco.packaging,rst.linker,pytest,pytest-checkdocs,pytest-flake8,pytest-cov,pytest-enabler,aiohttp,coverage,flake8,isort,pytest-aiohttp,sphinx,sphinx-issuess
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: even if i put pycryptodome in my requirements in the buildozer.spec file the app crashes because there is no module named crypto and yet i specified it in the requirements